# Spring Security ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, restful-authentication, restful-url, user-roles

I have a simple shopping application which has 2 types of roles "ADMIN" and "USER".

Controller method:

```java
@PostMapping("/admin/category/addProducts")
public void addProductsToCategory(@RequestBody Map input, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    try {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            logger.error(String.valueOf(bindingResult.getFieldError()));
            return;
        }

        String categoryName = input.get("cat_name").toString();
        Category category = categoryService.findByCategoryName(categoryName);
        if (category == null) {
            logger.error("Category %s not exists", categoryName);
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> products = new ArrayList();
        products.addAll((Collection) input.get("products"));

        for (LinkedHashMap map : products) {
            Product newProduct = new Product();
            newProduct.setName(map.get("name").toString());
            newProduct.setImageUrl(map.get("imageUrl").toString());
            newProduct.setDescription(map.get("description").toString());
            newProduct.setPrice(new BigDecimal(map.get("price").toString()));
            newProduct.setCategory(category);

            productService.save(newProduct);
            category.getProductsSet().add(newProduct);
        }

        categoryService.save(category);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(" Exception in adding new product to category");
    }
}
```

I call it from Postman with this values:

```
POST URL: http://localhost:8080/admin/category/addProducts
{
"cat_name": "Electronics",
"products": [
    {
        "name": "Monitor",
        "description": "Samsung 22' monitor",
        "imageUrl": "www.test.com",
        "price": "233.77"
    },
    {
        "name": "keyboard",
        "description": "A4tech new version keyboard",
        "imageUrl": "www.key.com",
        "price": "85.33"
    }
]
}
```

but when I send a request from the Postman, at the backend I don't receive the request.

The interesting part of the problem is that when `/admin` removes from the URL it works. I mean

```
(Backend Code)  @PostMapping("/category/addProducts")

(Postman) POST URL: http://localhost:8080/category/addProducts
```

Spring Security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/index", "/about", "/help", "/register", "/cart/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/product/new").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
           .ignoring()
               .antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/js/**", "/error/**",  "/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/libs/**","/img/**", "/h2-console/**");
    }

 //...  rest of code
}
```

Do you know where is the problem? Why I remove `/admin` from the URL works, and when I put `/admin` in address it does not work.

Is there any way to understand the role of users who sends a request from Postman? (In fact, I need `/admin` or `/user` at the beginning of the URL to understand the role of the user, and decide whether the user has the appropriate role to call a backend method or not.)

Comment: If you change the URL then every on could access it, because the changed URL is not restricted. Your problem is not the URL, your problem is that your user doesn't have the role "ADMIN".

Comment: where are your debug logs?